# Why is printf before exevp not running?

Tags: c, unix, exec, system-calls

I get an output of "hi!". Why is this not also printing "something"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* program_name = "echo";
    char* args[]= {program_name,"hi!",NULL};

    printf("something");
    execvp(program_name,args);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I'm not creating a child process first. If I take out the execvp line, it works as expected. Weird. (Note: "echo" refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string is in the io buffer - so pull the chain and flush that buffer

i.e. add

```
fflush(stdout)
```

after the `printf` (or add `\n` to the `printf`)

Comment: I'd just add, to fully answer the question, the `printf` is *indeed* running, it just doesn't flush the buffer, because the standard buffering mode of `stdout` is *line buffered*, so an automatic flush only happens at a newline character. Still, @andrew_ghobrial, it answers your question, so suggest to accept it.

Comment: To further clarify on what @FelixPalmen mentioned and to expand on this answer: stdio is line-buffered for terminal (or pseudoterminal) devices (and in general, for any interactive device), and fully-buffered for other file types (pipes, regular files, etc.) Thus, if output is being redirected to something that is not an interactive device, adding a `\n` is not enough; you'll have to explicitly flush the buffer with `fflush(3)`.